# speed of freezing vs. moving

Tags: speed-of-light, faster-than-light, freezing, cold-atoms

An idea came to my mind and like to discuss it.

We know that out there in the space the absolute zero (aka. -273 C) is almost reached where all the particles and atoms would freeze up and stop giving the matter its resilience and shape.

We know as well that for instance if water is to be thrown or poured in some freezing parts of the globe (e.g. Atartica or Nordic countries) where temperture is really really low it would freeze on its way or that might take few seconds no more. (even streams get to be frozen!)

So the questions is:

if superman to be real and that a human being is able to travel at speed fast enough or close to speed of light (I know that its mass would be enormous), what temperature would make him freeze instantly on his position before being able to travel or speed up? is absolute zero would make him frozen before being able to take decision of travelling?

Or would his speed generate energy enough to counter the temperture outside no matter what temperature it is so he keeps everything surrounding him warm due to his speed?

Let's sum it up to simple question:

Is there a formula/law that dictates the relation between the speed of freezing at certain temperature of a certain amount of mass against the the amount of required energy in order not to?

Comment: Space isn't absolute zero. Even far from any star it's a few degrees above absolute zero, due to cosmic microwaves.

Comment: yeah sure, I knew that... but here it is just an imaginary situation and some assumptions to play with!

Comment: 2nd paragraph is intended just to show an example of real-world case of instant freezing occurring by stopping atoms movements, I felt it not too good to insert it but just to clarify :/

Comment: Oh maybe that was a mis-expression, I don't mean the atom itself losing its shape, what I meant that atom will lose its energy due to the temperature exercised on it which will introduce new properties hence it will cause the whole body -in which it is part- to lose his original shape and resilience!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88843/discussion-between-pm-2ring-and-wisdom).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is based on a few misconceptions that come about because it is based on everyday physics and trying to apply it outside the normal context.

First, being surrounded by extremely low temperatures does not cause rapid freezing or other forms of energy loss. The reason the thrown water freezes is that it has a huge surface area to exchange heat with the cold air. But a thermos bottle will keep the contents warm since they are kept separated by a vacuum barrier from the outside. The only energy loss will be through inrared radiation and imperfections in the thermos. Same thing for an object in 0 K space. It will cool slowly due to heat radiation, but this also get slower the colder they are.

Second, while losing energy on Earth means objects stop moving, this is not true in space. You can have a 0 K object moving at any velocity in 0 K space. The reason is that the standard definition of heat, "the kinetic energy in how much the molecules are moving around" only deals with the random heat motions, not the overall motion of the object. In environments where you bump into stuff such motion will quickly produce heat, and if heat is leached away there will be energy loss.

Third, the universe is full of background radiation, currently at 3 K temperature. It is getting redhifted towards near absolute zero, but it is a slow process. In fact, the third law of thermodynamics tells us that we can never get to 0 K through any finite number of steps.

So Superman would not freeze in place. He would lose body heat (I assume Kryptonians are warm-blooded?) at some rate. Were he to just keep on flying he would eventually cool down to near absolute zero, but keep his enormous momentum.

There is a slight complication: he would also see the background radiation redshift behind him and blueshift in front of him, producing a very small radiation pressure against his motion if he travelled very close to lightspeed ($\gamma\approx 10^5$, [see this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.05845)). This would tend to slow him, but at a neglible rate.